# What are the benefits and/or pitfalls of calling a function directly from an anchor tag vs creating events onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a proper/standard way?

```
<a href="#" onclick="function();">Link</a>
```

vs

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#link1').click(function(){ ... });
});
</script>
<a href="#" id="link1">Link</a>
```

Comment: We have these sprinkled all over the place and I would love to find out the best way and create a standard.

Comment: Also, when would the first be used over the second? If ever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I prefer the second. It allows me to separate my markup and script. This means that scripts could be placed in a separate file and since scripts are static resources they get cached, minified, obfuscated, ... And reduced markup size obviously leads to reduced bandwidth and so faster loading site. In a web page there are really 3 notions that should not be mixed:

- markup
- scripting
- styling

Answer (score 2):

From the top of my head:

1. The first one only allows one handler per time on a single element
2. The first one cannot have access to anything but global scope
3. The first one doesn't allow for event delegation, because some events need to use event capture in standards compliant browsers for delegation to work (namely blur and focus), and you cannot select whether to use capture or bubble there.
4. The first one ... read @DarinDimitrov's answer.

You would use the first one when... ask facebook or hotmail. I've got nothing on that.

Answer (score 1):

My 2c:

Nowadays with the advent of heavy use of ajax and the versatility of jQuery, I like to centralize the processing management.

The

```
<a href='#' onClick= ...></a>
```

does not necessary require the href. On that, I, myself, avoid extra stress whenever not needed. So I do not code href on anchors that resolve to onClick. Secondly, unless I have a special need to manage anchors (like $('a ...)....), I do not use anchors either. I just use plain div or span or even paragraph (< p>).

the a (anchor) allows to automatic cursor:pointer and text-decoration handling for anchors.

The

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#link').click(...
```

is a good way to centralize processing where you can have all entries documented right there:

```
function a() { .. }
function b() { .. }
function c() { .. }
....

$(document).ready( function () {
    // originated on thatfile.html
    $('#clicka').click(a());
    // originated on thisfile.asp
    $('#clickb').click(b());
    // originated on form c in file myforms.asp
    $('#clickc').click(c());
});
```